# updating columns in multiple dataframes based on another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dictionary

I have five dataframes (df1, df2, df3, df4, df5) including multiple columns that need to be renamed. In a separate dataframe, which functions as a map for renaming (see the table below), I have three columns one including new variable names and the other two including the variables that need to be renamed from. Old variables1 refer to df1,2 and 3 while old_variables2 refer to df4 and df5.

| New variables | old variables1 | old variables2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DPG | DPG1, DPG2, DPG3 | DPG1, DPG2 |
| LMN | LMN1, LMN2, LMN3 | LMN1, LMN2 |
| CLG | CLG1, CLG2, CLG3 | CLG1, CLG2 |

I need to write a code using the map data to rename the columns in my five dataframes according to the New variables column in the map data. For instance, DPG1, LMN1, and CLCG1 belong to df1 and they should be renamed to DPG, LMN, and CLG. And the same for df2 and df3. I try to use a generic code because the information might be updated in my data files.
Can somebody give me some hints please?
I don't know how to deal with multiple values separated by commas in each cell in old variables column.

Thanks to @starja I have come up with a solution but still I have problem with the left join part of the function because it is wrong to include by = c("original_variables" = "old_variables1","old_variables2").

```
cols<- c(old_variables1, old_variables2)

rename_function <- function(col_names, rename_data = rename_info) {
for (col in cols) {
rename_info_clean <- separate_rows(rename_info,all_of(col))
}
data.frame(original_variables = col_names) %>% 
left_join(rename_info_clean , by = c("original_variables" = "old_variables1","old_variables2")) %>% 
mutate(final_name = coalesce(new_variables, original_variables)) %>% 
pull(final_name)
}
```

Comment: In other words, `df1$DPG1`, `df2$DPG2` and `df3$DPG3` need to be renamed to `df1$DPG`, `df2$DPG` and `df3$DPG` etc?

Comment: @AndreWildberg Yes, exactly.

Comment: You can try global assigning with `<<-`, it works but it's not really recommended. Something like `df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)` `sapply(1:nrow(df_nm), function(x) colnames(df_list[[x]])[grep(gsub(", ", "|", df_nm$old_variables[x]), colnames(df_list[[x]]))] <<- df_nm$New_variables[x])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution that uses `rename_with`:

```r
library(dplyr)
rename_info <- data.frame(
  new_variables = c("DPG", "LMN"),
  old_variables = c("DPG1, DPG2, DPG3", "LMN1, LMN2, LMN3"),
  old_variables_2 = c("DPG1, DPG2", "LMN1, LMN2")
)

test_data_1 <- data.frame(
  DPG1 = 1,
  LMN1 = 4,
  test = "a"
)

test_data_2 <- data.frame(
  DPG2 = 2,
  LMN2 = 5,
  other_name = 4
)

rename_function <- function(col_names, rename_data = rename_info) {
  rename_info_clean_1 <- rename_info %>% 
    tidyr::separate_rows(
      old_variables,
      sep = ",[ ]+"
    ) %>% 
    select(new_variables, old_variables)
  rename_info_clean_2 <- rename_info %>% 
    tidyr::separate_rows(
      old_variables_2,
      sep = ",[ ]+"
    ) %>% 
    select(new_variables, old_variables = old_variables_2)
  rename_info_clean <- bind_rows(
    rename_info_clean_1,
    rename_info_clean_2
  ) %>% 
    distinct()
  data.frame(original_variables = col_names) %>% 
    left_join(rename_info_clean, by = c("original_variables" = "old_variables")) %>% 
    mutate(final_name = coalesce(new_variables, original_variables)) %>% 
    pull(final_name)
}

test_data_1 %>% 
  rename_with(rename_function)
#>   DPG LMN test
#> 1   1   4    a

test_data_2 %>% 
  rename_with(rename_function)
#>   DPG LMN other_name
#> 1   2   5          4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Basically, `rename_function` first makes a data.frame where each old/new variable name combination is in its own row with `separate_rows`, an then it joins it with the available column names. When there is no match (e.g. for `test`), the join leads to `NA` which is replaced with the original name by `coalesce`.

### Edit

Now the `separate_rows` step is repeated and the results for the 2 columns stacked together.

Comment: Many thanks for the elegant solution. It works perfectly! Is it possible to include two columns in the separate_rows function? there is another column in my data (imagine two old_variables columns in the rename_info dataframe. I was wondering if I can include it in the code so that I do both columns in one go.

Comment: should be possible. Could you update your question with example data?

Comment: See my updated function

Comment: Amazing! Thank you Starja! In the whole code there is only one thing I don't understand. Could you kindly tell me why you wrote the following in line 13? select(new_variables, old_variables = old_variables_2). What does it mean when you say old_variables = old_variables_2?

Comment: I rename the variable `old_variables_2` to `old_variables`, because in the final `rename_info_clean` data.frame I only want one variable (`old_variables`) that I can use to match the old names to the new names

Comment: You taught me a lot. Thanks! If you are not bothered with me asking so many questions, could you also explain a bit about this part please? data.frame(original_variables = col_names) %>% left_join(rename_info_clean, by = c("original_variables" = "old_variables")). Why did we need to make a data frame?

Comment: `left_join` which matches the new with the old names only works on data.frames

Answer (score 1):

We could also use some `regex` to make a simpler function if the task is simply to remove the digits. Here using `tidyverse`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test_data_1 |>
  rename_with(~ str_extract(., "\\D+"))

test_data_2 |>
  rename_with(~ str_extract(., "\\D+"))
```

Output:

```
  DPG LMN test
1   1   4    a

  DPG LMN other_name
1   2   5          4
```

Thanks to @starja for the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work because I have several variables and in some cases the names are completely different.